# angular 5: how to import javascript specifically for this component. should not be available on other components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Currently**

in `game.component.ts` (route: `/play`)

```
import '../../assets/js/game.js';

export class PlayComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

`game.js` loads fine and starts the game on `domain.com/play`

**The Problem**

when i load `home.component.ts` (route: `/`) the game script is also imported and is appended. How can I get the game script to only load on `/play`? I know i can put the script in a function and only call that on the game component but I really want to avoid loading too much JS where it is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an "Angular" way to achieve what you want besides messing with the boodstrap/Webpack process.

Just use plain JavaScript.

Load the script within the `ngOnInit` hook of your `PlayComponent`. With that approach, the script will only ever get loaded when the component is created. You can also remove the script in the `ngOnDestroy` hook if you'd like:

```
@Component({})
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private assetService: AssetService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        assetService.loadScript('/assets/js/game.js').then(data => {
            console.log(data); // {loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'}
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        assetService.removeScript('/assets/js/game.js');
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class AssetService {
    removeScript(path: string) {
        // TODO: Remove DOM element that has attribute `data-path="${path}"`
    }

    loadScript(path: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = path;
            script.setAttribute('data-path', path);

            // IE
            if (script.readyState) {
                script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        resolve({ loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
                    }
                };
            } else {
                script.onload = () => {
                    resolve({ loaded: true, status: 'Loaded' });
                };
            }

            script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({ loaded: false, status: 'Loaded' });
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your imports used for the service. I am trying this out

Comment: Don't you use a modern IDE? It should highlight what's missing :P. Just `Injectable` and a `declare const document: any;`.

Comment: That works thanks! for an ide; what do you suggest? i use sublime

Comment: No problem. Try WebStorm, I use it and it's very nice. Visual Studio Code is nice as well, probably nicer than WebStorm for a lot of things, but I'm fine right where I am.